# How do I determine why my Azure server can see connections on one port but not another?

Tags: windows, azure, windows-server-2016, azure-networking

I've got a custom web server that I uploaded to an Azure VM running Windows Server.  It accepts HTTP connections on port 80, and websocket connections on port 2468.  Everything works fine locally, but on Azure, the HTTP connections will connect but the websocket connections won't.

In the Azure Network Security Group attached to the server, both ports are open for incoming TCP connections.  In the Windows firewall for the server, both ports are open for incoming TCP connections.  Netstat shows that my process is listening on port 2468, but Microsoft Network Monitor never shows any incoming connections on port 2468 when I try to connect from my browser.

All the stuff I know of to make sure the connection will work, I've done for both ports, and it works for port 80.  How do I figure out what's keeping my websocket connections from working?

Note: this is a custom server app, not running on IIS, Apache, etc.  Answers should be purely Windows Server/Azure related.

**EDIT:** To clarify, I'm attempting to connect from home, from an ordinary Web browser over an ordinary Internet connection, to the server's public IP.

**EDIT 2:** Upon further testing, trying to run the HTTP server on port 2468 and the websocket listener on port 80, I'm still able to connect on port 80 and not on port 2468.  So apparently it's not protocol related at all; even though both firewalls are open on both ports, stuff is only getting through on port 80...

Comment: How are you connecting to this service? From another Azure VM? From your office through a VPN? From the Internet? And in this case, are you using a public IP or an Azure Load Balancer?

Comment: Also, do you have a NSG on the Virtual Network too, other than on the server itself?

Comment: @Massimo Connecting from home, nothing weird with my Internet connection.  I only have the one NSG.

Comment: yes, but the VM its self will have windows firewall running, have you allowed it there?

Comment: @SamCogan Yes, I made sure to open it there.